# HTML hr tag for people with disabilities

Tags: html

In my code I use a `<hr>` tag.

```
// content

<hr>

//content
```

The problem is, that if a user with disabilities using a "Page Voice Reader" Software, that software/plugins try to read this divider. Depends on Plugin I hear

"dash dash dash dash dash"
or
"Divider"

I want to skip this tag. Like I wanna See this hr but not hear it. Is it possible to accomplish that? I need something like:

Comment: Then don't use this tag. This tag is for adding a divider. If you only need a visual border, use the `border` property in CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `aria-hidden` on HTML element to hide it from accessibility API.

```
<hr aria-hidden="true">
```